# Accessibility app for android that runs on top of all other applications and can intervene and send touch/tap events to views of other apps

Tags: android, overlay, accessibility

I have been trying to design an accessibility application for android for disabled people like that of ios7 switch control point mode. The biggest problem I am facing is how would I make an activity that would appear over all applications and takes switch events and send touch/tap events accordingly to any app over which it is running. I have searched and found that we could have a view that runs on top of other applications using system overlay mode but that does not let me send touch events. Please point me in right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want an Activity.  You want to develop and AccessibilityService.

http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html

Accessibility services receive callbacks from the accessibility apis, and are allowed to interact, draw views on top of, and send events to the applications that are running on the device.  Once you register yourself as an accessibility service, you have much more power over the way the OS works, than you do within the confines of an application activity.  You can even override touch events, and send your own!  Though advanced gesture control is lost, as the gestures that you send are within the confines of the accessibility framework.

Comment: Links to 404, here's a new link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service